# Como comparo 2 tuplas de diferentes tablas con el mismo tipo de dato?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quiero comparar que un nombre de un artista sea igual al nombre de una canción, con las siguientes relaciones:

Habia pensado en hacer un join entre artista y cancion con la condición que el id del artista sea igual que el artista de la canción, y de ahí poder comparando tupla a tupla con la condición dicha en el primer parrafo.

```
artista (id(PK), nombre, nombre_real, sigue_activo, pais_origen, anio_nacimiento)

cancion (nombre(pk), artista(fk y pk), duracion, descargas_actuales, anio_creacion)
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto

```
select * from [BASE].dbo.Cancion where nombre in (select nombre from [BASE].dbo.artista )
```